# Como enviar mensagem para stderr no bash via comando echo?

Tags: bash, echo

Estou escrevendo alguns script para deploy de uma aplicação e preciso enviar mensagens de status para o *stderr* ao invés do *stdout*, que o comando `echo` faz por padrão.
Como fazer o comando `echo` enviar a mensagem para *stderr* ao invés de *stdout*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
>&2 echo "erro"
```

ou

```
echo Esta mensagem vai para o stderr >&2
```

Fontes: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550347/194717 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422223/194717