# O que é e para que serve "2>&1"?

Tags: shell, redirecionamento

Quando pretendemos direcionar o output de forma a executar um comando sem receber qualquer informação, entre a qual potenciais erros de execução utilizamos:

```
meuComando >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Efetivamente com `>/dev/null` estamos a enviar o *output* para um ficheiro dispositivo que representa um vazio (buraco negro), mas o que é `2>&1` e para que serve ?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52622/ (ou dup?)

Comment: @bfavaretto Não tinha visto essa, mas a pergunta em si foca-se numa instrução diferente desta... Penso que as duas perguntas podem coexistir!

Comment: Também relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40254/como-enviar-mensagem-para-stderr-no-bash-via-comando-echo

Answer (score 33, accepted):

O comando `>` é equivalente a `1>`, e significa que se está redirecionado a saída padrão (*standard output* - `stdout`) para o arquivo indicado. Já o `2>` significa que se está redirecionando a saída de erro padrão (*standard error output* - `stderr`). Além do `1` e do `2`, há também o `0` que representa a entrada padrão (`stdin`).

Nesse caso, `meuComando` está redirecionando a saída padrão para `/dev/null`; a saída de erro também está sendo redirecionada, mas não para um arquivo, e sim para outra *stream*. Segundo [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/520779), o uso de `&` indica que a saída irá para outro *file descriptor*, e não para um arquivo. E como visto, o *file descriptor* `1` representa o `stdout`.

Portanto, `2>&1` significa "redirecione o `stderr` para o `stdout`". Como o `stdout` já está redirecionando para o "buraco negro", isso também será feito com o `stderr`. Mas mesmo que não estivesse, esse comando pode ser útil caso você queira enviar ambas as saídas para o mesmo destino, e não cada uma para um arquivo diferente:

```
meuComando > saida_e_erros.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Sua resposta está melhor que a do SOen, diga-se de passagem. Para dar minha contribuição, deixo o link do TLDP sobre redirecionamento de I/O (em inglês): http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 14):

1 significa o mesmo que `stdout` e 2 significa o mesmo que `stderr`, portanto é só uma forma mais simples de redirecionar tudo o que for enviado para a saída de erro para a saída padrão. O `&` é necessário para não haver confusão com um nome de arquivo. Sem ele a sintaxe poderia ser interpretada como o 1 sendo um nome de arquivo mas neste caso a sintaxe se refere a uma descritor de arquivo.

Então no seu exemplo não sairá nada na saída padrão porque você está anulando ela e também os resultados dos erros. Se apenas o `>/dev/null` fosse usado, os erros apareceriam.

Concluindo: os erros são direcionados para a saída padrão com a sintaxe `2>&1` e depois todas a saída padrão, incluindo o que foi redirecionada para ela é novamente redirecionada para `>/dev/null` que se encarregará de desaparecer com qualquer mensagem.

A confirmação pode ser obtida nas respostas dessa [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10508843/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).