# Esconder mensagens de erro

Tags: shell, shell-script

Considerem o seguinte shell script:

```
ping  8.asd.8.8 -c1 -q > /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
echo 'ok'
else
echo 'erro'
fi
```

Esse ping retornará um erro e esse erro é tratado no `else` logo abaixo. Mas mesmo usando o parâmetro `-q` o erro retornado pelo ping é escrito na tela:

```
ping: unknown host 8.asd.8.8
```

Existe alguma forma de ignorar esse erro? Mostrar apenas o erro tratado pelo `if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `&>`, que além de redirecionar o output padrão (stdout), redireciona erros também (stderr):

```
ping  8.asd.8.8 -c1 -q &> /dev/null
```

Comment: O `-q` neste caso não deve ser necessário pois o *stdout* e *stderr* serão redirecionados para `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 4):

Redirecione a saída de erros para `/dev/null`:

```
ping 8.asd.8.8 -c1 -q 2>/dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
echo 'ok'
else
echo 'erro'
fi
```

Mais informações: [**O que é e para que serve “2>&1”?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55765/6454)